# Proving that largest root (obtained via P.C.A.) is a symmetric function

Tags: roots, symmetric-functions

Suppose, we are given $\textbf{X} = (X_1, X_2, \ldots,X_m)$ and $\textbf{Y} = (Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n)$.

Also, we are given, S = pooled variance.

If we implement Principal Component Analysis (P.C.A.) using S, then how do I proceed in proving that $\lambda_1$ (= largest root obtained via P.C.A.) is a symmetric function of $\textbf{X}$ and $\textbf{Y}$ ?

Comment: A reference to the definition of PCA would be useful. If it is symmetric in the inputs, that should be enough.

Comment: @martycohen : I don't know what  means using the [pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance) for PCA, I guess you neither